# How to calculate mass of a closed Universe?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology

How does one integrate the mass density over a closed Universe (a 3-sphere?) to obtain the total mass of that Universe?

Is this the correct integral?

$$M = R(t)^3 \rho\int_0^1 4 \pi r^2 \frac{dr}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}$$

where $R(t)$ is the radius of the Universe at cosmological time $t$.

By making the substitution $r=\sin \chi$ one finds that the above integral gives:

$$M = \pi^2 R(t)^3 \rho$$.

According to wikipedia the [hyperarea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-sphere#Elementary_properties) of a 3-sphere is $2\pi^2 R^3$ so I'm out by a factor of two.

Answer (score 5):

Your integral is only half the sphere, because $r=0$ corresponds with the "north pole", while $r=1$ corresponds with the "equator". You can see that in the substitution $r=\sin\chi$: you see that $r=1$ means $\chi=\pi/2$. But for the entire sphere, the angle $\chi$ goes from $0$ to $\pi$, so that
$$
M = 4\pi\rho R^3(t)\int_0^\pi \sin^2\chi\,\text{d}\chi = 2\pi^2\rho R^3(t).
$$